# How to get all posts from facebook even those were geo targeted?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-timeline

I'm using graph API to get posts from facebook for a specific page, but there are some posts that are targeted to a specific region and those never come in the results.

I'm requesting posts like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/FBPage?fields=id,name,link,picture,posts{message,picture,link,likes,from,feed_targeting,targeting}
```

That's return all posts global posts but the geo targeted ones not.

Does anyone here know if there is any possibility to filter a specific region to get those posts or even request that facebook don't take in consideration the geo target information?

SOLVED: The problem was really with tokens, to solve we got a user that has access to all pages that we need and generate a token using its credentials, that token make all the magic happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can only try using a User Token, so you should get all those posts the User can see when he visits the Page manually. I assume you are using an App Token right now.

You can also try using a Page Token, in theory you should get all posts that way.

Comment: Yes luschn, I'm using an App Token.
I'm gonna try to use Page Token, if that works I will gonna have to change my solution a lot, but lets see.
Thanks luschn.

Comment: an extended page token is valid forever btw.: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: here´s a blogpost i wrote some time ago: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/